# Should I use "As of" or "Up to" or "Until"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, grammaticality

Which of these form can I use to submit presentation?

> This is the presentation **as of** Jun 30, 2018.
>   This is the presentation **until** Jun 30, 3018.
>   This is the presentation **up to** Jun 30, 2018.

I want to send presentation by email to my manager, and here is the sentence:

> Dear ____, I would like to submit the presentation for R project until June 30, 2018. I hope you like it.

Comment: It's not really clear to me exactly what you're asking about here. It does look quite a bit like Off Topic proofreading though. (Your "Dear ____" line looks highly suspect to me, but I don't actually know what you're *trying* to say anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Until and up to means:

Up to (the point in time or the event mentioned).

If you wanted extra time or an extension to complete your presentation then that's where until or up to is used:

> Can you give me **until/up to** Jun 30, 2018 to complete the presentation?

---

If you want to express that the aforementioned presentation was completed or ready to be submitted on Jun 30 2018, then it's:

> This is the presentation **as of** Jun 30, 2018

If so, it would be:

> Dear ............ , I would like to submit the presentation for R project **as of** June 30, 2018. I hope you like it, thank you very much."

Comment: I will use As of 
because today I finished the presentation 
thank you